# XSLT - Modifying value of a XML node depending on other nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT programming and struggling with the following issue:

**XML:**

```
<All_Results>
<Result>
<url>http://server/sites/sitecoll/library/Folder/NewFolder/test v1.0.docx</url>
<hithighlightedproperties>        
      <HHUrl>SomeValue1</HHUrl>
    </hithighlightedproperties>
<isdocument>True</isdocument>
<serverredirectedurl>SomeValue</serverredirectedurl>
</Result>
<Result>
<url>http://server/sites/sitecoll/library/NewFolder1/test v2.0.docx</url>
<hithighlightedproperties>        
      <HHUrl>SomeValue1</HHUrl>
    </hithighlightedproperties>
<isdocument>True</isdocument>
<serverredirectedurl>SomeValue</serverredirectedurl>
</Result>
<Result>
<url>http://server/sites/sitecoll/library/NewFolder/test v1.0.docx</url>
<hithighlightedproperties>        
      <HHUrl>SomeValue1</HHUrl>
    </hithighlightedproperties>
<isdocument>False</isdocument>
<serverredirectedurl>SomeValue1</serverredirectedurl>
</Result>
......
......
```

**Following is the requirement:**

For each "Result" section, 
  if ("isdocument" node = True),
    read the "url" node and get substring after 'library/' in it's value. From this output, 
    get the substring before the last occurrence of '/'. (Used separate a template to 
    achieve this) For example, for the first "Result", it will be "Folder/NewFolder". 
    Finally, concatenate hard-coded strings before and after this output and replace the 
    values of "HHUrl" and "ServerRedirectUrl" with this final output for every "Result" 
    under "Results".

**Output**

```
 <All_Results>
<Result>
<url>http://server/sites/sitecoll/library/Folder/NewFolder/test v1.0.docx</url>
<hithighlightedproperties>        
      <HHUrl>http://SomeHardCodedString1/Folder/NewFolder/SomeHardCodedString2</HHUrl>
    </hithighlightedproperties>
<isdocument>True</isdocument>
<serverredirectedurl>
        http://SomeHardCodedString1/Folder/NewFolder/SomeHardCodedString2
    </serverredirectedurl>
</Result>
<Result>
<url>http://server/sites/sitecoll/library/NewFolder1/test v2.0.docx</url>
<hithighlightedproperties>        
      <HHUrl>http://SomeHardCodedString1/NewFolder1/SomeHardCodedString2</HHUrl>
    </hithighlightedproperties>
<isdocument>True</isdocument>
<serverredirectedurl>http://SomeHardCodedString1/NewFolder1/SomeHardCodedString2
     </serverredirectedurl>
</Result>
<Result>
<url>http://server/sites/sitecoll/library/NewFolder/test v1.0.docx</url>
<hithighlightedproperties>        
      <HHUrl>SomeValue1</HHUrl>
    </hithighlightedproperties>
<isdocument>False</isdocument>
<serverredirectedurl>SomeValue1</serverredirectedurl>
</Result>
......
......
```

I have trimmed the original XML output to simplify the requirement and have a long complex XLST associated with the original XML. The goal is to modify the "HHUrl" string on the fly before it is rendered as HTML. For this particular requirement, I have created and embedded the following code, which works partially:

```
<xsl:template name="stripLast">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>
    <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="'/'"/>
     <xsl:if test="contains($pText, $pDelim)">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $pDelim)"/>
       <xsl:if test="contains(substring-after($pText, $pDelim), $pDelim)">
         <xsl:value-of select="$pDelim"/>
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:call-template name="stripLast">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
          "substring-after($pText, $pDelim)"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="pDelim" select="$pDelim"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  

 <xsl:template match="All_Results/Result/hithighlightedproperties/HHUrl">  
     <xsl:param name="staticUrl" select=" 'https://SomeHardCodedString1/' "/> 
      <xsl:copy>  
      <xsl:variable name="urlValue" select="string(.)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="s" select="substring-after($urlValue, 'Portal/')"/>      
      <xsl:variable name="qsValue">
      <xsl:call-template name="stripLast">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$s"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($staticUrl, $qsValue, 'SomeHardCodedString2')"/>        
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

SharePointDev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bit of a play around, the following idea might be useful. It will be a bit fragile though, if there are more than two levels in the bit you want to hard-code around (ie. "Folder/", "Folder/Folder1/", (and it breaks if), "Folder/Folder1/Folder2/"), but you could extend the idea:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//HHUrl[ancestor::Result[isdocument[.='True']]]">
    <xsl:variable name="url" select="../../url"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="firsttoken" select="concat(substring-before(substring-after($url,'library/'),'/'),'/')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="secondtoken" select="substring-before(substring-after($url,$firsttoken),'/')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="thirdtoken" select="concat($firsttoken,$secondtoken)"></xsl:variable>

    <HHUrl>http://SomeHardCodedString1/<xsl:if test="$secondtoken!=''"><xsl:value-of select="$thirdtoken"/></xsl:if><xsl:if test="$secondtoken=''"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($firsttoken,'/')"/></xsl:if>/SomeHardCodedString2</HHUrl>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//serverredirectedurl[ancestor::Result[isdocument[.='True']]]">
    <xsl:variable name="url" select="../url"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="firsttoken" select="concat(substring-before(substring-after($url,'library/'),'/'),'/')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="secondtoken" select="substring-before(substring-after($url,$firsttoken),'/')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="thirdtoken" select="concat($firsttoken,$secondtoken)"></xsl:variable>

    <serverredirectedurl>http://SomeHardCodedString1/<xsl:if test="$secondtoken!=''"><xsl:value-of select="$thirdtoken"/></xsl:if><xsl:if test="$secondtoken=''"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($firsttoken,'/')"/></xsl:if>/SomeHardCodedString2</serverredirectedurl>

</xsl:template>
```