# XSLT - extract string value and format date

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following **XML**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FilterPanel>
<FilterCategory DisplayName="Publication Date" ShowMoreLink="True">
<Filters>
  <Filter>
    <Value>Any Publication Date</Value>
    <Tooltip>Any Publication Date</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Implied</Selection>
    <Count></Count>
    <Percentage></Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>Before 2013-11-08T03:49:32.4999680Z</Value>
    <Tooltip>Before 2013-11-08T03:49:32.4999680Z</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>From 2013-11-08T03:49:32.4999680Z to 2013-11-08T09:46:47.4999808Z</Value>
    <Tooltip>From 2013-11-08T03:49:32.4999680Z to 2013-11- 
08T09:46:47.4999808Z</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>From 2013-11-08T09:46:47.4999808Z to 2013-11-08T16:23:55.9998464Z</Value>
    <Tooltip>From 2013-11-08T09:46:47.4999808Z to 2013-11-   
        08T16:23:55.9998464Z</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>2013-11-08T16:23:55.9998464Z or later</Value>
    <Tooltip>2013-11-08T16:23:55.9998464Z or later</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
</Filters>
</FilterCategory>
 <FilterCategory DisplayName="Review Date" ShowMoreLink="True">
<Filter>SameasPublciationDateOutput</Filter>
</FilterCategory>
<FilterCategory DisplayName="TEST" ShowMoreLink="True">
<Filter></Filter>
</FilterCategory>
</FilterPanel>
```

For the FilterCatergories with DisplayName as Publication Date and Review Date, I want the change the date format of Value node in

> DDMMYYYY HH:MM

format in the given value.

The Output should be like as follows:

```
<FilterCategory DisplayName="Publication Date" ShowMoreLink="True">
<Filters>
  <Filter>
    <Value>Any Publication Date</Value>
    <Tooltip>Any Publication Date</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Implied</Selection>
    <Count></Count>
    <Percentage></Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>Before 08-11-2013 03:49</Value>
    <Tooltip>Before 08-11-2013 03:49</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>From 08-11-2013 03:49 to 08-11-2013 09:46</Value>
    <Tooltip>From 08-11-2013 03:49 to 08-11-2013 09:46</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>08-11-2013 09:46 to 08-11-2013 16:23</Value>
    <Tooltip>08-11-2013 09:46 to 08-11-2013 16:23</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>08-11-2013 16:23 or later</Value>
    <Tooltip>08-11-2013 16:23 or later</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
</Filters>
```

I am new to XSLT and not very sure how to achieve this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you could try Regex. You don't need XSLT for this.

Comment: It would probably be easier with a regex in any language you prefer because with XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0 it won't be easy to cover every case. Or with extension functions which are proprietary with XSLT 1.0 and "standard" with XSLT 1.1 (working draft, not a recommendation). Can't you use XSLT 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 wouldn't be my first choice of language for this but something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="text()[contains(.,'T') and contains(.,'Z')]" name="T">
      <xsl:param name="t" select="." />
      <xsl:variable name="a" select="substring-before($t,'T')" />
      <xsl:variable name="l" select="string-length($a)" />
      <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring($a,$l - 1,2)" />
      <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring($a,$l -4,2)" />
      <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring($a,$l -9,4)" />
      <xsl:variable name="b" select="substring-after($t,'T')" />
      <xsl:variable name="c" select="substring-before($b,'Z')" />
      <xsl:variable name="z" select="substring-after($b,'Z')" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($a,1,$l -10),$d,'-',$m,'-',$y,' ', substring($c,1,5),' ',$z)" />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="text()[contains(.,'T') and contains(.,'Z') and contains(.,' to ')]" priority="2">
      <xsl:call-template name="T">
         <xsl:with-param name="t" select="substring-before(.,' to ')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>to</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="T">
         <xsl:with-param name="t" select="substring-after(.,' to ')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

input:

```
<FilterPanel>
<FilterCategory DisplayName="Publication Date" ShowMoreLink="True">
<Filters>
  <Filter>
    <Value>Any Publication Date</Value>
    <Tooltip>Any Publication Date</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Implied</Selection>
    <Count></Count>
    <Percentage></Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>Before 2013-11-08T03:49:32.4999680Z</Value>
    <Tooltip>Before 2013-11-08T03:49:32.4999680Z</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>From 2013-11-08T03:49:32.4999680Z to 2013-11-08T09:46:47.4999808Z</Value>
    <Tooltip>From 2013-11-08T03:49:32.4999680Z to 2013-11-08T09:46:47.4999808Z</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>From 2013-11-08T09:46:47.4999808Z to 2013-11-08T16:23:55.9998464Z</Value>
    <Tooltip>From 2013-11-08T09:46:47.4999808Z to 2013-11-08T16:23:55.9998464Z</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>2013-11-08T16:23:55.9998464Z or later</Value>
    <Tooltip>2013-11-08T16:23:55.9998464Z or later</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
</Filters>
</FilterCategory>
 <FilterCategory DisplayName="Review Date" ShowMoreLink="True">
<Filter>SameasPublciationDateOutput</Filter>
</FilterCategory>
<FilterCategory DisplayName="TEST" ShowMoreLink="True">
<Filter></Filter>
</FilterCategory>
</FilterPanel>
```

---

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><FilterPanel>
<FilterCategory DisplayName="Publication Date" ShowMoreLink="True">
<Filters>
  <Filter>
    <Value>Any Publication Date</Value>
    <Tooltip>Any Publication Date</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Implied</Selection>
    <Count/>
    <Percentage/>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>Before 08-11-2013 03:49 </Value>
    <Tooltip>Before 08-11-2013 03:49 </Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>From 08-11-2013 03:49  to 08-11-2013 09:46 </Value>
    <Tooltip>From 08-11-2013 03:49  to 08-11-2013 09:46 </Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>From 08-11-2013 09:46  to 08-11-2013 16:23 </Value>
    <Tooltip>From 08-11-2013 09:46  to 08-11-2013 16:23 </Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <Value>08-11-2013 16:23  or later</Value>
    <Tooltip>08-11-2013 16:23  or later</Tooltip>
    <Selection>Deselected</Selection>
    <Count>1568</Count>
    <Percentage>0.25</Percentage>
  </Filter>
</Filters>
</FilterCategory>
 <FilterCategory DisplayName="Review Date" ShowMoreLink="True">
<Filter>SameasPublciationDateOutput</Filter>
</FilterCategory>
<FilterCategory DisplayName="TEST" ShowMoreLink="True">
<Filter/>
</FilterCategory>
</FilterPanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

`([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}).([0-9]*)(Z|[+-]?[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})`

replace with

`\3\2\1 \4:\5`

Is the incoming format fixed ? XSD dateTime ? Or might be different ?
dateTime could have timezones like +/-02:30, instead of Z. You should take them into account.

Comment: Well, how the OP is going to evaluate your regex ? In an XSLT 1.0 environment ? You clearly do not answer the question unless he is able to parse the XML document as text using a programming language.

Comment: Why do you need XSLT environment ? If you're in Java use String.replace, if you're in some other programming language use that regex support, if you're in SOA use some XPath function that works with regex.

Comment: The XSLT transformation could be invoked by a mean which does not give you the ability to execute arbitrary code on the XML document. The OP has to clarify this as no programming language is mentioned. We do not know the environment of XSLT (context of invocation).

Comment: He picked XSLT because he needs to change something in a text fragment, which happens to be an XML. XSLT isn't the answer to all processing of XMLs. I think XSLT is irrelevant here.

Comment: Cosmin and Ikuty, Thank you for your inputs. Sorry, I would have made it more clear before. I need to achieve this by modifying an existing XSLT (related to a MS SharePoint Search Refinement Panel WebPart)  and I do not have any other way. The results are rendered as HTML on the basis of this XSLT with the given XML. I have a similar situation before and was resolved by modifying an XSLT. Please refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008838/xslt-modifying-value-of-a-xml-node-depending-on-other-nodes.  Also the date format is fixed .

Comment: You were wrong Cosmin and in fact nothing in the OP question could have made you think XSLT is irrelevant as the question focused mainly on XSLT.

Comment: Check if your implementation allows you to use extension functions. Otherwise, I can't see a way to solve your problem.